# How to resolve Page unresponsive Error in Chrome, when launched Angular application

Tags: angular, angular-http

In my angular application, I am reading a excel file and from the read data construct the request payload and make the HTTP call.

Reading the file and constructing the request object taking long time when the excel file has huge data and chrome shows the "Page Unresponsive" message.

Here is my code to read file.

```
onImport(evt) {

let filename = evt.target.files[0];
let reader = new FileReader();
reader.onloadend = function () {

// here I do some manipulations on read data which takes long time and freezes the UI as well
//once manipulations done I send http requests  
Observable.from(readData)
.concatMap((data)=>{
    this.http.post(url,data);
})
reader.readAsText(evt.target.files[0], "UTF-8");
}
```

is there any way to avoid this Error?

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this issue, Just putting answer here in case required,

I was doing manipulation on all data and then sending requests with concatMap, now instead I am sending request as soon as manipulation of one object is done. Which solved issue for me.